# Ubuntu PHP-CLI and Apache Different Versions

Tags: php, mongodb, ubuntu-14.04

Does anyone know why a fresh install of Ubuntu with Apache and PHP-CLI is installing two different versions of PHP?

For Apache its running 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.19 and PHP-CLI is running PHP 5.6.24-1+deb.sury.org~trusty+1

Is there anyway to get them on the same?  I'm running into all sorts of issues with installing modules.  For example this:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: mongo: Unable to initialize module Module
>   compiled with module API=20121212 PHP    compiled with module
>   API=20131226 These options need to match

Any clear direction you can give would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try to set path for cli same as apache(5.9). change envirnonment variables and 
Your path for 5.9 can be different depending upon your installation.

```
set PATH="/usr/lib64/php5.9/bin:$PATH"
```

then run `php -v`